# in puppet, what's the difference between "include 'module::config'" and "include '::module::config'"?

Tags: puppet

I have inherited a module that contains the include statement

```
include '::module::config'
```

but after editing a few things that seems to be unrelated, this doesn't work anymore and puppet complains that:

```
    err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: 
    Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Could not 
    find declared class ::module::config at /home/user/svn-workspace/puppet
    /user/modules /module/init.pp:28 on node host.acme.com
```

unless I change it to:

```
include 'module::config'
```

then it starts working again.

Answer (score 4):

Using `::` at the start specifies top scope.

If your classes are structured in a normal way, this should never matter.  It can matter if you have classes with name collisions; for instance, if you have a class at `module::stuff` and a module named `stuff`, then an `include stuff` from within `module::things` will include `module::stuff` instead of `stuff`.

So, using `include ::stuff` is a workaround for that, telling the lookup that you want top scope.  This workaround is documented [here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_namespaces.html#relative-name-lookup-and-incorrect-name-resolution).

---

So.. take a look at your module structure and see if `module::config` is a sub-module of the module you're including from.  If not, then something else is causing the problem; can you provide more information about what changes you made?